# Creating financial chart in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to develop a application which should generate dynamic financial chart and i tried using Graphics class but its not look good...
Is there any concepts in blackberry, where i can draw chart like following image

http://news.timtechs.com/our-favorite-blackberry-app-world-picks.html/bloomberg-blackberry-app

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is any API that will let you to do that.

However, you will easily do that width all basics [Graphics](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html) functions... with drawLine, drawRect, drawText, etc...